# Number of 3-point lines on a NxM grid

Tags: geometry, combinations

How many collinear point triples can be chosen on a NxM grid?

I have:

$$
    {N\choose{3}} \times M + {M\choose{3}} \times N
$$

Which is far from being correct I know, since at least it does not consider tilted lines.

Comment: For orthogonal lines, you shouldn't have the last multiply.  The first term says pick a column, then three points in it, or pick a row, then three points in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#(M,N) = #(M-1,N)+#(M,N-1)-#(M-1,N-1)+#{all of the triples with one end point on the Mth row and one endpoint on the Nth column}+#{All of the triples with endpoints 1,1 and M,N}

= #(M-1,N)+#(M,N-1)-#(M-1,N-1)+#(M-1,N)+#(M,N-1)-2*#(M-1,N-1)+#{All of the triples with endpoints 1,1 and M,N}+#{All of the triples with endpoints M,1 and 1,N}

= 2*#(M-1,N)+2*#(M,N-1)-3*#(M-1,N-1)+2*(gcd(M,N)-1)

which isn't super pretty, but I think it's accurate.